# How to incorporate I parameter in GRETL application for ARIMA model?

Tags: econometrics, time-series

How to incorporate I parameter in GRETL application for ARIMA model?

Able to incorporate parameter AR and MA but not sure how to incoporate the I parameter?

Comment: Have you checked first Gretl's user guide, and then, did you e-mail the support gretl-users@lists.wfu.edu ? These are the primary sources for a definitely reliable answer.

Answer (score 2):

In gretl, the command

arima 1 3 ; y

will estimate an ARMA(1,3) model on y. However, the syntax

arima 1 2 3 ; y

will estimate an ARIMA(1,2,3) model on y, that is, an ARMA(1,3) model on y, differenced twice.

You also have ways to estimate models with seasonal filters etcetera. You'll want tpo have a look at:

- the help provided in the program abot the "arima" command, and
- chapter 25 of the User's Guide.

The User's Guide is accessible from within the program via the Help menu, or can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gretl/files/manual/

Answer (score 1):

What you do with the I-term in ARIMA is to make the series stationary, so an easy way to do this is to take the difference of the series (increasing the magnitude until you reach stationarity) and create a new series. Then use the ARMA-model on that.